# Best practices for creating partition schemes and functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, best-practices, partitioning

I'm implementing partitioning for the first time in SQL Server 2008 R2. I've several large tables that I am partitioning.

My main question is: Should I use the same Partition Scheme and Function for all these tables, or should I create multiple Partition Schemes and Functions?

When I move older data to a different file group, will having separate Schemes and Functions make moving the data easier?

And what are some things that I should consider when making this decision?

Comment: I had accomplished the partition of a big table in SQL Server just some days ago. Now,I'm preparing for the other big tables. I think partition function can reuse,but partition scheme not.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a single schema and function and you alter that to move data around all the tables will be moved in a single shot instead of having to change all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new to partitioning as well, but already have done some maintenance on them and thats what can suggest now:

- It is easier to maintain as less PF/PS as possible. Don't overrcommit into creating multiple filegroups either.
- Transferring data between filegroups is very expensive operation for large tables 10GB+. Even fast 15k RPM drives suffer. So it is better to keep data in same filegroups if possible.

In our environment I tried different partition schemes: 1) across several filegroups and 2) single filegroup. The maintenance costs for multiple filegroups didn't look worthwile (1TB database). This might be different in your case if you have larger database.